# CPU access for textures with MTLResourceStorageModePrivate storage mode is disallowed.'

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, error-handling, mapbox

I have a login page on my app. If I lock my screen and change orientation of the app, when I unlock the phone again my app crashes. In my xCode debugger this error pops up.

```
_validateGetBytes:29: failed assertion `CPU access for textures with MTLResourceStorageModePrivate storage mode is disallowed.'
```

[image]

How can I fix this error?
I'm using MapBox in my app.

Comment: Thanks for the report! Folks can also follow discussion of this issue on Github: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/15806

Comment: Do you have any background process that change element of your map ? It happened to me because I added a timer that changed an annotation coordinate.
I think the problem is that it's impossible to make UI processing on map when app is in background.

Comment: @nelsonPARRILLA that's an interesting notion. I'll run a few tests and see if that's the cause. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @nelsonPARRILLA that is an interesting notion. I did find out that the issue was on overloading of the map box API. Due to my initial view process and user interface transition, there was multiple initialisations of the mapbox view upon reopening.